# Add sessions for ASP.NET 5 controller unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core

After we added sessions in our asp web app, now our controller unit tests fail:

```
data_browser.Tests.HomeControllerTests.Index [FAIL]
  System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Tests fail on a statement where we use sessions:

```
HttpContext.Session.SetString("games", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(games));
```

Looks like as a session service needs to be added. In our app it is done through Startup class's methods:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add MVC services to the services container.
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddSession();
        services.AddCaching();
    }
```

and

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        app.UseSession();
        ...
    }
```

But when we unit test, we just instantiate our controller smth like this:

```
HomeController homeCtrler = new HomeController();
JsonResult jsonResult = (JsonResult)homeCtrler.Smth();
Assert.Eq(bla, bla);
```

So is there a way to inject sessions for controller in asp.net 5 unit tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example (from https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/blob/master/test/MusicStore.Test/ShoppingCartControllerTest.cs):

```
// Arrange
var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
httpContext.Session = new TestSession();

var controller = new ShoppingCartController()
controller.ActionContext.HttpContext = httpContext;

// Act
var result = await controller.Index();

//--------------

class TestSession : ISession
{
    private Dictionary<string, byte[]> _store
        = new Dictionary<string, byte[]>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    public IEnumerable<string> Keys { get { return _store.Keys; } }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _store.Clear();
    }

    public Task CommitAsync()
    {
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    public Task LoadAsync()
    {
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    public void Remove(string key)
    {
        _store.Remove(key);
    }

    public void Set(string key, byte[] value)
    {
        _store[key] = value;
    }

    public bool TryGetValue(string key, out byte[] value)
    {
        return _store.TryGetValue(key, out value);
    }
}
```